# Alert triggering when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a basic software development course. For my assignment I have to create a simple translator program in JavaScript. It has various requirements, and one is that if the user doesn't enter German or French when prompted for a language they are to receive a message saying "only French or German is allowed". But when I try to implement this in an "if" statement the alert triggers regardless... Code below!

```
var german = ["Eins","Zwei","Drei","Vier","Fünf","Sechs","Sieben","Acht","Neun","Zehn","Elf","Zwölf","Dreizehn","Vierzehn","Fünfzehn","Sechzehn","Siebzehn","Achtzehn","Neunzehn","Zwanzig","Einundzwanzig","Zweiundzwanzig","Dreiundzwanzig","Vierundzwanzig","Fünfundzwanzig","Sechsundzwanzig","Siebenundzwanzig","Achtundzwanzig","Neunundzwanzig","Dreiβig"];
var french = ["un","deux","trois","quatre","cinq","six","sept","huit","neuf","dix","onze","douze","treize","quatorze","quinze","seize","dix-sept","dix-huit","dix-neuf","vingt","vingt et un","vingt-deux","vingt-trois","vingt-quatre","vingt-cinq","vingt-six","vingt-sept","vingt-huit","vingt-neuf","trente"];
var translatedNumber;
var lang;

function translate (number,lang) {
    translatedNumber = (lang[number]);
    return translatedNumber;
}
if (isNaN(number)){
    alert("Please use digits");
}else if ((number <1)||(number >30)){
    alert ("Please type an integer number between 1 and 30");
}else{
    var lang = prompt("Please enter the language (french/german)").toLowerCase();

if (lang !="german"||"french") {
   alert ("Only French or German is allowed");
}

if (lang=="german") {
    translate(number-1,german);
    alert (translatedNumber);
}
else if (lang=="french") {
    translate(number-1,french);
    alert (translatedNumber);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
if (lang !="german"||"french") {
```

This should be like this:

```js
if (lang !="german" && lang != "french") {
```

Little side-note: you could have the same result with a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/switch) statement, it will be easier if you plan to add more languages.

```js
switch (lang) {
    case 'german':
        translate(number-1,german);
        alert(translatedNumber);
        break;
    case 'french':
        translate(number-1,french);
        alert(translatedNumber);
        break;
    default:
        alert('Only French or German is allowed');
        break;
}
```